# Lagrangians related by field redefinition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Is there a sufficient criteria in the form of a theorem to check if two Lagrangian densities $\mathscr{L}$ are related via field redefinitions $\phi\rightarrow f(\phi)$, where $f(\phi)$ is an analytic function of $\phi$? For simplicity let's assume the Lagrange densities only depend on a scalar field $\phi$.

Comment: They should give the same $S$-matrix

Comment: So, you're saying that: "Same S-Matrix => Related by field redefinition"? If yes, do you have a reference for that? I have been searching for quite some time now